# Why no Array.prototype.flatMap in javascript?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

`flatMap` is incredibly useful on collections, but javascript does not provide one while having `Array.prototype.map`. Why?

Is there any way to emulate `flatMap` in javascript in both easy and efficient way w/o defining `flatMap` manually?

Comment: *"Why?"* Because no one made a proposal yet? [Here is how to propose a new feature](https://github.com/tc39/ecma262/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md#proposals). *"Is there any way to emulate flatMap ... w/o defining flatMap manually?"* Uh? I don't understand. You mean like `arr.reduce((arr, v) => (arr.push(...v), arr), [])`?

Comment: (^that's only the flatten part, so I guess it should be `arr.map(...).reduce(...)`).

Comment: You could just [flatten](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10865025/merge-flatten-an-array-of-arrays-in-javascript) the array after `.map`ping it.

Comment: Hmm, you want to "emulate" it but not "define" it. What might that mean?

Comment: emulate = being able to use `flatMap`-like functionality via existing js functions. e.g. something like `[1, 2, 3].flatMap(x => [x, x]).flatten()`. Except a) there is no `flatten` b) it is ineffective and c) it could be shorter

Comment: @FelixKling There was a proposal in Brian Terlson's github to add it to JS but I can't find it now.

Comment: It is going to be part of JS soon.
https://tc39.github.io/proposal-flatMap

Answer (score 119, accepted):

**Update:** [`Array.prototype.flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) made it into ES2019

It is widely supported in many environments. See if it works in your browser using this snippet below -

```js
const data =
  [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ]
  
console.log(data.flatMap(x => Array(x).fill(x)))
// [ 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4 ]
```

---

***"Why no Array.prototype.flatMap in javascript?"***

Because programming isn't magic and every language doesn't have features/primitives that every other language has. What matters is JavaScript gives you the ability to define it on your own -

```js
const concat = (x,y) =>
  x.concat(y)

const flatMap = (f,xs) =>
  xs.map(f).reduce(concat, [])

const xs = [1,2,3]

console.log(flatMap(x => [x-1, x, x+1], xs))
```

Or a rewrite that collapses the two loops into one -

```js
const flatMap = (f, xs) =>
  xs.reduce((r, x) => r.concat(f(x)), [])

const xs = [1,2,3]

console.log(flatMap(x => [x-1, x, x+1], xs))
```

If you want it to extend the `Array.prototype`, nothing is stopping you -

```js
if (!Array.prototype.flatMap) {
  function flatMap (f, ctx) {
    return this.reduce
      ( (r, x, i, a) =>
          r.concat(f.call(ctx, x, i, a))
      , []
      )
  }
  Array.prototype.flatMap = flatMap
}

const ranks =
  [ 'J', 'Q', 'K', 'A' ]
  
const suits =
  [ '♡', '♢', '♤', '♧' ]

const result =
  ranks.flatMap(r =>
    suits.flatMap(s =>
      [[r, s]]
    )
  )

console.log(JSON.stringify(result))
// [ ['J','♡'], ['J','♢'], ['J','♤'], ['J','♧']
// , ['Q','♡'], ['Q','♢'], ['Q','♤'], ['Q','♧']
// , ['K','♡'], ['K','♢'], ['K','♤'], ['K','♧']
// , ['A','♡'], ['A','♢'], ['A','♤'], ['A','♧']
// ]
```

Comment: It is considered better to namespace any additions to prototypes (e.g. `Array.prototype._mylib_flatMap`), or even better use ES6 symbols, instead of simply defining `Array.prototype.flatMap`.

Comment: @FengyangWang *"considered better"* is highly subjective. If this is your own app and you have a reason for extending your prototypes, there is nothing wrong with it. If it is an library/module/framework that you are distributing for others' use, then I would agree with you. Comments however are not the place to discuss this - the matter deserves more explanation and detail than should be provided in comments.

Comment: First is ugly: flatMap defined as function will make code a mess - imagine functional code with `map` defined as global function! Second is just bad practice

Comment: @SergeyAlaev re: *"imagine map as a global function"* haha I do exactly that on lots of my utility functions. I curry them too using sequences of arrow functions. "Ugly" is subjective. And you've made no argument to support your "bad practice" comment. Your remarks indicate to me you have little experience with functional programming. Take a language like Haskell where prelude include heaps of "globals"... no one is saying it's "ugly" or a "bad practice". You're just not familiar with it.

Comment: @SergeyAlaev or consider Racket that has `append`, `map`, `filter`, `foldl`, `foldr` among countless others in the default namespace. It doesn't make it a bad practice because you heard someone say "globals are bad" or "extending natives is bad" - racket is amongst the best designed languages. You just don't know how/when to do it appropriately.

Comment: @user633183 ""_considered better_" is highly subjective." No, it's not. It's conditional. Subjective isn't a synonym for conditional. Anyway, you outline those conditions in your first reply:

"If it is your own app [...] there is nothing wrong with it."
"If it is an library/module/framework that you are distributing for others' use, **then I would agree with you.**"

I feel like this info should be in the body of the answer, as it's kinda important?

Comment: I think they just want an IIFE `;(()=>{/* that code  */})();`

Comment: Why is your order the parameters in a python-like map function call? I have always seen it written as iterable, followed by function in JavaScript. The thing that is being operated on is usually the most important thing and importance is usually left-to-right in JavaScript.

Comment: It's not really important (and unrelated to Python) as you can define the function parameters for your program in any order of your choosing. You have seen `iter.map(func)` in JavaScript which is infix notation, popular with object-oriented style. In functional style, prefix notation like `map(func, iter)` or `map(iter, func)` are more common. Many popular functional languages put the "most important thing" last to enable easier function composition and partial function application.

Comment: @elliott-jones Loved the distinction subjective/conditional.

Answer (score 52):

`flatMap` has been approved by  the TC39 as part of ES2019 (ES10). You can use it like this:

```
[1, 3].flatMap(x => [x, x + 1]) // > [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Here's my own implementation of the method:

```
const flatMap = (f, arr) => arr.reduce((x, y) => [...x, ...f(y)], [])
```

[MDN Article on flatMap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap)

Comment: In particular, flapMap is officially in Node 11.0.0 according to MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap#Browser_compatibility

Comment: @CarlWalsh I'm sorry, I cannot resist. What the heck is `flapMap`? i want to flatten my map, not flap it!

Comment: On another subject, this finally turns JavaScript Array's into Monads™️ 

Answer (score 11):

I know you said you didn't want to define it yourself, but [this implementation](https://gist.github.com/samgiles/762ee337dff48623e729) is a pretty trivial definition.

There's also this from the same github page:

Here is a bit of shorter way using es6 spread, similiar to renaudtertrais's - but using es6 and not adding to the prototype.

```
var flatMap = (a, cb) => [].concat(...a.map(cb))

const s = (v) => v.split(',')
const arr = ['cat,dog', 'fish,bird']

flatMap(arr, s)
```

Would either of these help?

It should be noted (thanks to @ftor) that this latter "solution" suffers from "Maximum call stack size exceeded" if called on a really large (e.g., 300k elements) array `a`.

Comment: This implementation may blow up the stack for large arrays.

Comment: Just to be clear, if I understand you correctly, @ftor, you're talking about the recursive implementation in the link I gave, not the one I show in the code block at the end of my answer, right?

Comment: Try `[].concat(...(new Array(300000).fill("foo").map(x => x.toUpperCase())))`. Sure, it's a corner case. But you should at least mention it.

Comment: Thanks. I added a note to this effect.

Answer (score 7):

[Lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/#flatMap) provides a flatmap function, which to me is practically equivalent to Javascript providing it natively. If you're not a Lodash user, then ES6's `Array.reduce()` method can give you the same result, but you have to map-then-flatten in discrete steps.

Below is an example of each method, mapping a list of integers and returning only the odds.

**Lodash:**

```
_.flatMap([1,2,3,4,5], i => i%2 !== 0 ? [i] : [])
```

**ES6 Reduce:**

```
[1,2,3,4,5].map(i => i%2 !== 0 ? [i] : []).reduce( (a,b) => a.concat(b), [] )
```

Answer (score 4):

One fairly concise approach is to make use of the `Array#concat.apply`:

```js
const flatMap = (arr, f) => [].concat.apply([], arr.map(f))

console.log(flatMap([1, 2, 3], el => [el, el * el]));
```

Answer (score 1):

I did somthing like this:

```
Array.prototype.flatMap = function(selector){ 
  return this.reduce((prev, next) => 
    (/*first*/ selector(prev) || /*all after first*/ prev).concat(selector(next))) 
}
```

`[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]].flatMap(i => i); //[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]`

`[{subarr:[1,2,3]},{subarr:[4,5,6]},{subarr:[7,8,9]}].flatMap(i => i.subarr); //[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]`

Comment: Hi serhii,
I have tried this code, when parent only one object will gives unexpected result.
```
Array.prototype.flatMap = function(selector){
  if (this.length == 1) {
      return selector(this[0]);
  }
  return this.reduce((prev, next) =>
    (/*first*/ selector(prev) || /*all after first*/ prev).concat(selector(next)))
};
```

Answer (score 1):

We now have a `flatMap()` in Javascript! And it is supported [pretty well](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap#Browser_compatibility)

> The flatMap() method first maps each element using a mapping function,
>   then flattens the result into a new array. It is identical to a map()
>   followed by a flat() of depth 1

```js
const dublicate = x => [x, x];

console.log([1, 2, 3].flatMap(dublicate))
```

Comment: Getting error when running the posted code `{
  "message": "Uncaught TypeError: [1,2,3].flatMap is not a function",
  "filename": "https://stacksnippets.net/js",
  "lineno": 15,
  "colno": 23
}`

Comment: What broser are you using? Edge, IE and Samsung Internet does not support it yet, thoug, Edge will soon run on V8. So to support those, you could use a polyfil

Comment: Chrome Version 67.0.3396.87 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: Your browser is outdated.. You should update it or set to update itself automaticly.

Answer (score 0):

`Array.prototype.flatMap()` has now arrived in JS. However, not all browser might support them check for the current browser compatibility the [Mozilla web docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap).

What the `flatMap()` method does is first maps each element using a callback function as argument, then flattens the result into a new array (the 2d array is now 1d since the elements are flattened out).

Here is also an example of how to use the function:

```js
let arr = [[2], [4], [6], [8]]

let newArr = arr.flatMap(x => [x * 2]);

console.log(newArr);
```