# How to, with a one-lined solution, can I reduce an object containing arrays of arrays of objects to the inner objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects, sub-array

I have the following object structure:

```
regions: [
  {
    name: reg1, 
    subregions: [
      {name: subreg11},
      {name: subreg12}
    ]
  },
  {
    name: reg2, 
    subregions: [
      {name: subreg21},
      {name: subreg22}
    ]
  }
]
```

What I'd like, is to extract an array of the subregions, like so:

```
[{name: subreg11}, {name: subreg12}, {name: subreg21}, {name: subreg22}]
```

...and I'd like to do that with a one-line array.prototype-function, like .filter, .map, .forEach etc.

I've managed to do it in three lines like this (including the return-statement, which I'd like to have in the one-liner):

```
let subregions = []
regions.forEach(reg => reg.subregions.forEach(subregion => subregions.push(subregion)))
return locs
```

Does anyone know how I could do this?

**EDIT July 2020**: I see the question has been marked as a duplicate by [@nina-sholz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1447675/nina-scholz), but I don't believe this is true. The linked question asks "[Why no Array.prototype.flatMap in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39837678/why-no-array-prototype-flatmap-in-javascript)", while my question was a description of a way to solve a problem. I didn't request the flatMap function specifically, and marking this as a duplicate simply says "you should have intuitively known that `Array.prototype.flatMap` was the thing you were looking for".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`flatMap` and extract the `subregions` property:

```js
const regions = [
  {
    name: 'reg1',
    subregions: [
      {name: 'subreg11'},
      {name: 'subreg12'}
    ]
  },
  {
    name: 'reg2', 
    subregions: [
      {name: 'subreg21'},
      {name: 'subreg22'}
    ]
  }
];

const output = regions.flatMap(({ subregions }) => subregions);
console.log(output);
```

You can also use `reduce`:

```js
const regions = [
  {
    name: 'reg1',
    subregions: [
      {name: 'subreg11'},
      {name: 'subreg12'}
    ]
  },
  {
    name: 'reg2', 
    subregions: [
      {name: 'subreg21'},
      {name: 'subreg22'}
    ]
  }
];

const output = regions.reduce((a, { subregions }) => a.concat(subregions), []);
console.log(output);
```

Pretty much any Javascript code can be reduced into a single line, but it won't necessarily be readable.

Comment: Oh didn't knew about `flatMap`, i use map and than flat, +1

Answer (score 1):

You can use `map` and `flat`

```js
const regions = [{name: 'reg1',subregions: [{name: 'subreg11'},{name: 'subreg12'}]},{name: 'reg2', subregions: [{name: 'subreg21'},{name: 'subreg22'}]}];
const output = regions.map(({ subregions }) => subregions).flat();
console.log(output);
```