# How do i use spread operator over spread operator | Typescript

Tags: typescript

I'm not sure if I'm doing this the right way ( Let me know )..  Lets say

```
let myFruits = [
    ...(['apple', 'grapefruit', 'pear'].map((fruit) =>
        [
            fruit,
            'red ' + fruit,
        ]
    ))
]

console.log(myFruits) //[["apple", "red apple"], ["grapefruit", "red grapefruit"], ["pear", "red pear"]]
```

What i want is

```
["apple", "red apple", "grapefruit", "red grapefruit", "pear", "red pear"]
```

I tried doing... ( it gives an error )

```
let myFruits = [
    ...(['apple', 'grapefruit', 'pear'].map((fruit) =>
        [
            fruit,
            'red ' + fruit,
        ]
    )).map((fr)=>...fr)
]
```

Comment: You don’t want the spread-operator; Use the `flatMap` function instead (`flatMap` is JS’ equivalent of Linq’s `SelectMany`).

Comment: This here contains bunch of workarounds for the case that your environment does not support `flatMap`: [Why no Array.prototype.flatMap in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39837678/why-no-array-prototype-flatmap-in-javascript) (in JS, it became available only relatively recently).

Comment: Alternatively, use the fact that `flatMap` is just `map` followed by `flatten`, and use `[].concat(...lists)` as replacement for `lists.flatten()`. In your case, it would be something like `[].concat(...(['foo', 'bar'].map(x => [x, 'red ' + x]))`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `reduce`:

```js
const FRUITS = ['apple', 'grapefruit', 'pear']

const result = FRUITS.reduce<string[]>(
    (acc, elem) => [...acc, elem, `red ${elem}`], []
)
```